# NIFI CLUSTER AND ZOOKEEPER CLUSTER

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi

I want to configure a NIFI Cluster with external TLS zookeeper cluster (deployed in a kubernetes cluster). All is ok (quorum, zookeeper tls...) but when I set the zookeeper connection string to … myzk:3181,myzk2:3181… and Nifi tries connect to zookeeper cluster, I get this message :

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 0000002d0000

I think that is because Nifi is talking with zookeeper HTTP and the 3181 is HTTPS

Thanks in advance, regards

NIFI Version : 1.12.1
Zookeeper 3.7.0 (QUORUM IS OK)

```
#nifi.properties

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=nifi-0.nifi-headless.nifi-pro.svc.cluster.local
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.contents.cache.expiration=30 secs

# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.proxy.host=my_proxy.com

nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.https.port=9443

nifi.web.http.host=nifi-0.nifi-headless.nifi-pro.svc.cluster.local
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=eth0
nifi.web.https.host=nifi-0.nifi-headless.nifi-pro.svc.cluster.local
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
# nifi.web.proxy.context.path=

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=


nifi.security.keystore=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/config-data/certs/keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=jks
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=tym6nSAHI7xwnqUdwi4OGn2RpXtq9zLpqurol1lLqVg
nifi.security.keyPasswd=tym6nSAHI7xwnqUdwi4OGn2RpXtq9zLpqurol1lLqVg
nifi.security.truststore=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/config-data/certs/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=wRbjBPa62GLnlWaGMIMg6Ak6n+AyCeUKEquGSwyJt24
nifi.security.needClientAuth=true
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer



nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=

nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=


# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=https://my_url_oidc
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=lkasdnlnsda
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=fdjksalfnslknasfiDHn
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=email
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=



# Apache Knox SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.knox.url=
nifi.security.user.knox.publicKey=
nifi.security.user.knox.cookieName=hadoop-jwt
nifi.security.user.knox.audiences=

# Identity Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing user identities such that identities coming from different identity providers
# (certificates, LDAP, Kerberos) can be treated the same internally in NiFi. The following example demonstrates normalizing
# DNs from certificates and principals from Kerberos into a common identity string:
#

# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?), O=(.*?), L=(.*?), ST=(.*?), C=(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.kerb=^(.*?)/instance@(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.kerb=$1@$2

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=true

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=nifi-0.nifi-headless.nifi-pro.svc.cluster.local
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11443
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=1 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=nifi-zk:2181
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
nifi.zookeeper.client.secure=true

## BY DEFAULT, NIFI CLIENT WILL USE nifi.security.* if you require separate keystore and truststore uncomment below section

nifi.zookeeper.security.keystore=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/config-data/certs/zk/keystore.jks
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystoreType=JKS
nifi.zookeeper.security.keystorePasswd=123456
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststore=/opt/nifi/nifi-current/config-data/certs/zk/truststore.jks
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststoreType=JKS
nifi.zookeeper.security.truststorePasswd=123456


# Zookeeper properties for the authentication scheme used when creating acls on znodes used for cluster management
# Values supported for nifi.zookeeper.auth.type are "default", which will apply world/anyone rights on znodes
# and "sasl" which will give rights to the sasl/kerberos identity used to authenticate the nifi node
# The identity is determined using the value in nifi.kerberos.service.principal and the removeHostFromPrincipal
# and removeRealmFromPrincipal values (which should align with the kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal and kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal
# values configured on the zookeeper server).
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=

# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principal #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principal #
nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=
```

Answer (score 1):

You usually see this when you have a **HTTP** vs **HTTPS** mismatch

ideally you would be calling your service over the HTTP

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          url-expression: "'lb:http://'+serviceId"
```

For reference using client port **2181**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-hs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2888
    name: server
  - port: 3888
    name: leader-election
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-cs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 2181
    name: client
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: zk-pdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zk
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  serviceName: zk-hs
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zk
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - zk
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-zookeeper
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: "k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "0.5"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: client
        - containerPort: 2888
          name: server
        - containerPort: 3888
          name: leader-election
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "start-zookeeper \
          --servers=3 \
          --data_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data \
          --data_log_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data/log \
          --conf_dir=/opt/zookeeper/conf \
          --client_port=2181 \
          --election_port=3888 \
          --server_port=2888 \
          --tick_time=2000 \
          --init_limit=10 \
          --sync_limit=5 \
          --heap=512M \
          --max_client_cnxns=60 \
          --snap_retain_count=3 \
          --purge_interval=12 \
          --max_session_timeout=40000 \
          --min_session_timeout=4000 \
          --log_level=INFO"
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datadir
          mountPath: /var/lib/zookeeper
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

NiFi did not support TLS with ZooKeeper until release 1.13.0. If you're using NiFi 1.12.1 it will not support configuring TLS for ZooKeeper.

Comment: Thank so much @returntosender404, I upgraded to 1.14 (and yesterday to 1.15.2) and it worked, but a I think that the HTTPS zookeeper communication code is not stable. Suddenly the cluster down without obvious reason and I need restart the cluster. Finally, I disabled HTTPS communication and everything is ok :)

Comment: If you have logs that demonstrate the issue you could add a Jira ticket to Apache NiFi project: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI/issues